React Three Drei, PivotControls, Scaling Handle Not Showing Up. Scaling is Not Disabled
PivotControls is supposed to have scaling handles too. But they are not showing up:

Here's the code snippet
        <PivotControls
          autoTransform={true}
          depthTest={false}
        >
          <mesh>
            <sphereGeometry />
            <meshBasicMaterial color={'hotpink'} />
          </mesh>
        </PivotControls>

The docs say I can disable scaling using this prop
/** Allows you to disable scaling */
disableScaling?: boolean`

but this prop does not exist on my PivotControls. I am using version "@react-three/drei": "^9.80.3". The example given in the docs is using version "@react-three/drei": "9.47.1" . I have the newer version. But in the example the scaling handles and showing and they work:
Here's the example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/object-gizmo-controls-om2ff8?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A8%2C5-8%2C35
here are the docs: https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#pivotcontrols
